# Asp.NET Development Server DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: asp.net

The TempImage is located under the root directory of the current web app. When I try to set the ImageUrl of an image I get the error below. For some reason asp.net web server trying to locate the directory under its own current root

This is what I am trying to do:

```
<asp:image ImageUrl="~/TempImages/... />
```

Ive also tried

```
<asp:image ImageUrl="/TempImages/... />
<asp:image ImageUrl="./TempImages/... />
<asp:image ImageUrl="TempImages/... />
```

Returns this error:

Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\9.0\TempImage

Answer (score 1):

If the image is in the root of the current application just specify:

```
<asp:image ImageUrl="~/imagename.jpg" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I am doing and I get the error Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\9.0\TempImage\image.jpg

Comment: are you using cassini (mini IIS for visual studio) or do you have this setup in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the asp.net user account has permissions to the directory. The cause can be that due to lack of permissions, other paths are being tried.